# Peano arithmetics formulae examples

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

Help me please to come up with an example of two arithmetic formulae $\varphi$ and $\psi$ such that $PA\vdash\varphi\vee\psi$, but neither $\varphi$ nor $\psi$ is derivable in $PA$ ($PA$ is Peano arithmetics)

Upd: I made a mistake, so, formulae must not have any free varibles

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $\exists k (x=s(s(0)) \times k)$ and $\lnot \exists k (x=s(s(0)) \times k)$

Comment: What does symbol $\times$ mean? Is it casual multiplication?

Comment: "casual" ?????   But yes; obviously is multiplication,

Comment: Even easier: $x=0$ and $\neg(x=0)$.

Comment: Upd: I made a mistake, so, formulae must not have any free varibles

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to showing that PA is an incomplete theory, which is a consequence of Godel's incompleteness theorem. That is, by the theorem, there exists $\varphi$ such that neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$ is derivable from PA. Then just take $\psi$ to be $\neg\varphi$. (I should add that this obviously assumes that PA is consistent)

Comment: Of course, there exist such formulae, but Godel's incompleteness theorem doesn't give us an example for that :(

Comment: @КириллКуценок What do you mean it doesn't? The incompleteness theorem implies that PA is incomplete (assuming it is consistent). By definition of "incomplete" this means that there exists a sentence $\varphi$ such that PA can neither prove nor disprove $\varphi$.

Comment: @КириллКуценок I think I see. You want an $\textit{explicit}$ example?

Comment: Yes, you're rigth

Comment: @КириллКуценок I see. There aren't very simple answers to that question. If you follow Godel's proof, you'll see that the sentence "This sentence is not provable in PA" is one example for $\varphi$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205178/how-would-i-show-that-pa-proves-the-godel-sentence-for-pa-implies-conpa for a more precise statement). For other interesting examples, see https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-simple-propositions-in-the-theory-of-Peano-arithmetic-that-the-theory-can-neither-prove-nor-disprove-How-would-one-go-about-attempting-to-find-such-propositions.

Comment: There might be some easier answers, i think. Maybe not using of $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$

Comment: @КириллКуценок No there won't be. If you could find sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$ such that PA$\vdash\varphi\lor\psi$ but neither $\varphi$ nor $\psi$ is derivable from PA, then either $\varphi$ or $\psi$ must be undecidable in PA. Thus, there won't be an easier answer than the ones I've given you.

Comment: In fact, both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ will be undecidable in PA.

Comment: Can you please help me to create a formula out of the sentence "This sentence is not provable in PA" in PA?

Comment: Any detailed textbook presentation of Gödel's incompleteness theorem gives you *instructions* of how to produce such a PA sentence (but will inevitably use  a stack of formal abbreviations for long PA expressions, without which the whole thing will become totally unreadable).